# HTML file appears as plaintext when piped/streamed to browser

Tags: html, node.js, express, web, browser

I have this Express handler

```
router.get('/', ac.allow('Admin'), function (req, res, next) {

  let html = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../coverage/lcov-report/index.html');

  fs.createReadStream(html).pipe(res);

});
```

the problem is that the file is sent to the browser, *but it just appears as plain text and does not get rendered*...kind of funny, but makes sense. Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html` to tell the browser what your response actually is.

Comment: I've been overly reliant on express to set those headers for me